# use of setNeedsDisplay

Tags: ios, uiview, setneedsdisplay

I'm confused with the different use of `setNeedsDisplay` to update an `UIView`? I do get an error message ("`No visible @interface for viewcontroller declares the selector setNeedsDisplay`") when I try to use:

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

I found out that I have to ignore the argument to make it work for UIViews:

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay]
```

Why is the argument for the UIView update not needed here? (A lot of answers for how to use `setNeedsDisplay` suggests the first approach)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

case sensitivity matters, b.t.w.

change that to:

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

And as you've discovered, you call "`setNeedsDisplay`" on the UIView object, not the UIViewController (which is the "`No visible @interface for viewcontroller declares the selector 'setNeedsDisplay'`" error you were seeing).

[The place where "`setNeedsDisplay:`" takes a YES or NO parameter is on the Macintosh side](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/setNeedsDisplay%3a), in NSView.

Comment: I got rid of the mistakes thanks. Is there a reason why the argument in iOS is not needed or is it just the way the iOS method works?

Comment: [That's just the way it's defined in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/setNeedsDisplay).  My guess is that you looked at the documentation for "`setNeedsDisplay`" on Apple's website, saw a parameter but didn't notice that it was for NSView and not UIView. And don't feel bad. I make this mistake sometimes, too (but the compiler will always catch me). Not all the API's are uniform between architectures, yet.